# Update ObservableArray - Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/kcFpS/5/

Each row will have an 'Edit' button. On clicking this,

1. It should fill the row values in the respective textboxes below the table. eg: 'productName' will fill in txtName, etc.
2. Editing the text in the textbox will reflect the change in the table.

But the foll. code is not working :

```
<td>
   <button data-bind="click: $parent.editProduct">Edit</button>
</td>

function Product(Name,Qty) {
            pname = ko.observable(Name);
            qty = ko.observable(Qty);
        }

        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.products = ko.observableArray([{ pname: 'Mobile', qty: 5 },
                                            { pname: 'Car', qty: 1}]);

            self.SelectedItem = ko.observable(new Product());                

            self.editProduct = function (item) {
                self.SelectedItem(item);
            };
};  

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: what's the problem? your jsfiddle is working fine. But you don't have to do `attr: {disable:...}`, knockout provided `disable` and `enable` binding out of the box. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html

Comment: Sorry. Wrong Url.Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question. You need to implement editing array of data. I sketched for you an example:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var $scope = this;

$scope.array = ko.observableArray([]);
$scope.array.push({ name: ko.observable('Ben'), lastName: ko.observable('Afleck'), editMode: ko.observable(false) });
$scope.array.push({ name: ko.observable('Tom'), lastName: ko.observable('Cruse'), editMode: ko.observable(false) });

$scope.toggleEdit = function(data) {
if (data.editMode()) {
data.editMode(false);
console.log(data.name());
console.log(data.lastName());
}
else
data.editMode(true);
};
return $scope;
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9X3er